# What does Guice need it own thread?

Tags: guice

What does Guice need it's own thread? I'm optimizing my app and I see there's a Guice thread called "com.google.inject.internal.util.$Finalizer".

Ideally I don't want this extra thread.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a part of Guava library. Here is its original version in Guava code: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/base/internal/Finalizer.java

And this is the version of this class from Guice:
http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/source/browse/core/src/com/google/inject/internal/util/Finalizer.java?r=86142556d360048671dc129f7b0c316f542473af

BTW, in the next commit after the one I have linked to this class was removed from Guice, and Guice started to depend on Guava. Nice!

This thread seems to be spawned by `FinalizableReferenceQueue` ([API](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/FinalizableReferenceQueue.html), [source](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/base/FinalizableReferenceQueue.java)). I don't know how exactly Guice uses `FinalizableReferenceQueue` (I suspect that it is indirect, something like "Guice → Guava cache → `FinalizableReferenceQueue`"), but it seems to be a fail-safe measure for not leaking out closeable resources. I'm pretty sure that you won't be able to get rid of that thread unless it is caused to appear by optional part of Guice (which is unlikely).